In the godot documentation in the 3d fps tutorial, one line of code is outdated and im new to coding so I don't know how to fix it
In the 3d fps tutorial godot documentation, there is a line of code near the bottom that's outdated. I am new to coding with godot, I have a little bit of experience with java script but that's it. The line of code looks like this.
VVV
vel = move_and_slide(vel, Vector3(0, 1, 0), 0.05, 4, deg2rad(MAX_SLOPE_ANGLE))
I know to fix the deg2rad part, it should be deg_to_rad, but once I do that it gives me this error.
Too many arguments for "move_and_slide()" call. Expected at most 0 but received 5.
I don't know what to try because like I said I am new to coding with godot, I understand a little bit of GDScript, but not enough to fix this problem on my own.

If you find errors in the documentation please report them to https://github.com/godotengine/godot-docs

As the error message says, move_and_slide() doesn’t take any parameters anymore since Godot 4. Instead you’re supposed to assign the CharacterBody3D’s velocity property, then call move_and_slide().
I recommend you check out some of the example projects from the Asset Library, where you may find code like this:
var input_dir := Input.get_vector("move_left", "move_right", "move_forward", "move_backward")
var direction := input_dir.rotated(-global_rotation.y)

velocity.x = lerp(velocity.x, direction.x * speed, accel * delta)
velocity.z = lerp(velocity.z, direction.y * speed, accel * delta)
velocity.y -= gravity * delta

move_and_slide()


Instead you’re supposed to assign the CharacterBody3D’s velocity property, then call move_and_slide()
What would that look like, code wise?

I posted example code in my answer? It’s supposed to be inside your player controller, so the velocity property that is being assigned belongs to the player’s CharacterBody3D. The direction is taken from the pressed action buttons (eg. WASD) then rotated according to the player’s own rotation, so that “forward” is ”direction in which I’m looking”. IIRC it’s inverted because in Godot it’s customary to use -Z as forward.
